# How can I select a somewhat dynamic ID based on the index position?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I will try to explain what I mean first.

In a drop down menu, there are 5 buttons, 2 of them have static IDs (meaning they are hardcoded), 3 of them can be changed through a different micro service (when you change the break type for example). The IDs for these 3 buttons are generated based on the name of the break type, but they always end up with _ButtonId" and usually contain the word "Break".

It looks something like this, I removed everything else from the div to keep it short:

```
  <div class="user-status__group">
   <button id="logoutButtonId"  </button>
   <button id="activateButtonId"  </button>
   <button id="RestroomBreak_ButtonId"  </button>
   <button id="LunchBreak_ButtonId" </button>
   <button id="TechnicalBreak_ButtonId"  </button>
 </div>
```

I use testcafe and what I want to achieve is to be able to have 3 different buttons for these breaks.
Something like breakButtonOne = *break_ButtonId[1]
breakButtonTwo = *break_ButtonId[2]

I tried something like based on things I've read online / through documentation:

```
  private breakBtnOne = Selector("[id$='_ButtonId']:eq(1)");
```

OR

```
  private breakBtnOne = Selector('[id$="_ButtonId"]:nth-child(1)')
```

This didn't seem to work, first one returns an error that it is not a valid selector, the second one can't find button, in this case, the first break button from that list.

Can you please point me in the right direction? I checked some testcafe documentation, but it suggests I should use attributes instead of IDs, which is not an option for me because the whole UI has react components/containers and some UI fragments. The IDs are based on what is in the UI fragment, they are not static, but still mentain something like ThisSection_anId_ButtonId and the attributes change.

I'm using this basic example so I can understand how I should proceed further because I'm totally not an expert in TypeScript / JS. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to selecting elements by a partial attribute value is correct. In addition, you can use the `nth` method to find an element with the specified index.

Please refer to the following articles:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/nth.html

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#select-elements-with-dynamic-ids

I created an example to demonstrate how it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="user-status__group">
    <button id="logoutButtonId">b1</button>
    <button id="activateButtonId">b2</button>
    <button id="RestroomBreak_ButtonId">b3</button>
    <button id="LunchBreak_ButtonId">b4</button>
    <button id="TechnicalBreak_ButtonId">b5</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `D:\\projects\\tests\\index.html`;

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click(Selector('[id$=_ButtonId').nth(0));
    await t.click(Selector('[id$=_ButtonId').nth(1));
    await t.click(Selector('[id$=_ButtonId').nth(2));
});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Good to know I had the right approach, but the wrong execution.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript you can use the below code it will give you array of all the id ending with **_ButtonId**.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_ButtonId"]')
```

after that you can use index to access whatever element you wish to access.